# Why does this vector derivation hold?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, optimization, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

I have the following variables/matrices:

$$A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}
, \quad p \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, \quad \Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}, \quad w \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$$

where $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix. With these we define function $S(p)$ as $$S(p) = (w + Ap)^{T} \Sigma^{-1} (w + Ap)$$

Since we would like to find the minimum of $S(p)$ we compute the first derivation with respect to $p$, according to my master's solution this is $$\nabla S(p) = 2(Ap + w)^{T} \Sigma^{-1} A \overset{!}{=} 0$$

However I don't understand how they arrive at this solution, could somebody please explain the intermediary steps?

Comment: You can often compute derivatives using the equation $S(p + \Delta p) \approx S(p) + \langle \nabla S(p), \Delta p \rangle$.  (The approximation is good when $\Delta p$ is small.)  If you write out $S(p + \Delta p)$ explicitly and disregard "higher order" terms, then $\nabla S(p)$ will appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a look at the derivative with respect to the first coordinate.

First we apply the product rule.
Then we note that the expression is a scalar, so we can also write it as a transpose. The transpose of a scalar is trivially the same as the scalar.

\begin{aligned}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} S(p) 
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( (w+Ap)^T \Sigma^{-1} (w+Ap) \right) \\
&= \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(w+Ap)\right)^T \Sigma^{-1} (w+Ap) + (w+Ap)^T \Sigma^{-1} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(w+Ap) \\
&= \left(\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(w+Ap)\right)^T \Sigma^{-1} (w+Ap)\right)^T+ (w+Ap)^T \Sigma^{-1} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(w+Ap) \\
&= (w+Ap)^T \Sigma^{-1} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(w+Ap)+ (w+Ap)^T \Sigma^{-1} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(w+Ap) \\
&= 2 (w+Ap)^T \Sigma^{-1} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(w+Ap) \\
&= 2 (w+Ap)^T \Sigma^{-1} (A\hat x)
\end{aligned}

More generally, we can write this as:
$$\nabla_i S(p) = 2 (w+Ap)^T \Sigma^{-1} (A e_i)$$
Or:
$$\nabla S(p) = 2 (w+Ap)^T \Sigma^{-1} (A I) = 2 (w+Ap)^T \Sigma^{-1} A$$

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a typo "$\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$". It must be "$\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$" (since in the definition of $S(p)$ it's multiplied by the vectors of the same dimension from both sides). Use the following vector derivation rules ($\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is the dot product in $\mathbb{R}^n$):

1. $\nabla_p \langle p, c \rangle = c$, where $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a constant (w.r.t. $p$) vector.
2. $\nabla_p \langle Ap, p \rangle = (A + A^T)p$, where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$  is a constant (w.r.t $p$) matrix.
3. $\langle x, y \rangle = x^T y$.

So we can write

$S(p) = \langle \Sigma^{-1}(w + Ap), (w + Ap)\rangle = \langle \Sigma^{-1}w, w \rangle + \langle \Sigma^{-1}w, Ap \rangle + \langle \Sigma^{-1}Ap, w \rangle + \langle \Sigma^{-1}Ap, Ap \rangle = \{\Sigma \text{ is symmetric}\} = \langle \Sigma^{-1}w, w \rangle + 2 \langle A^T \Sigma^{-1}w, p\rangle + \langle A^T\Sigma^{-1}Ap, p\rangle.$

Hence  (using the rules above):

$\nabla_p S(p) = 2A^T\Sigma^{-1}w + (A^T\Sigma^{-1}A + (A^T\Sigma^{-1}A)^T)p = 2A^T\Sigma^{-1}w + 2A^T\Sigma^{-1}Ap = 2A^T\Sigma^{-1}(w + Ap) = (2(Ap + w)^T\Sigma^{-1}A)^T = 0.$

Transposing both sides we get the equality from your master's solution.