# confusion about matrix derivation

Tags: matrices, partial-derivative

In the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/885507/1052540) here,
\begin{aligned}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} S(p) 
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( (w+Ap)^T \Sigma^{-1} (w+Ap) \right) \\
&= \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(w+Ap)\right)^T \Sigma^{-1} (w+Ap) + (w+Ap)^T \Sigma^{-1} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(w+Ap) \\
&= \left(\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(w+Ap)\right)^T \Sigma^{-1} (w+Ap)\right)^T+ (w+Ap)^T \Sigma^{-1} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(w+Ap). \\
\end{aligned}

My question:

Why is it that $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(w+Ap)\right)^T \Sigma^{-1} (w+Ap) = \left(\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(w+Ap)\right)^T \Sigma^{-1} (w+Ap)\right)^T$?

Comment: Just expand $S(p+h)-S(p)$ and drop the higher order terms.

Comment: The quantity on LHS is a ***scalar.*** $\:$ Treating it as a $1\times 1$ matrix, it is obviously equal to its own transpose.